# Html5 pattern that check for at least 2 digits and at least 4 letters in any order

Tags: regex, html, validation

I'm using the Html5 pattern to validate password and I need to make sure that the string contains at least 2 numbers and at least 4 letters in any order.

I did and this is what I got so far: `[a-z]{4,}[0-9]{2,}|[0-9]{2,}` but I need it to be in any order, for example: `9pog8k`.

If I have 2 numbers and 4 letters in any order than it's fine no matter what else I have.

Thanks!

Comment: Please advice what should be the pattern > Please create my pattern for me.
How about you try and create something yourself first

Comment: I did and this is what I got so far:
[a-z]{4,}[0-9]{2,}|[0-9]{2,}
but I need it to be in any order, for example: 9pog8k

Comment: But does it mean the password can only contain letters and digits? Or any characters?

Comment: If I have 2 numbers and 4 letters in any order than its fine no matter what else I have. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[a-z]{4,}[0-9]{2,}|[0-9]{2,}` matches 4 or more letters + 2 or more digits, OR 2 or more digits, from start will end as `pattern` regex is anchored by default.

You need to use *lookaheads* to actually check if any pattern appears inside the string in any order, not a simple alternation:

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){4})(?=(?:\D*\d){2}).*" title="Min. 2 digits and min. 4 letters are required"/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

The HTML5 pattern attribute needs a full string match, so `.*` at the end is necessary.

**Pattern details**:

- `(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){4})` - there must be 4 sequences of 0+ non-letters followed by a letter
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){2})` - there must be 2 sequences of 0+ non-digits followed by a digit
- `.*` - match any characters, 0+ occurrences

Comment: That's it. Thanks again.